# Creating time series data from table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have a table which looks something like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
tmp=[["","5-9",""],["","",""],["17-","","4- -9 27-"],["-6","",""],["","","-15"]]
dat=pd.DataFrame(tmp).rename(columns={0:"V0",1:"V1",2:"V2"})
dat["Month"]=np.arange(1,6)
dat["Year"]=np.repeat(2015,5)

    V0   V1         V2  Month  Year
0       5-9                 1  2015
1                           2  2015
2  17-       4- -9 27-      3  2015
3   -6                      4  2015
4                  -15      5  2015
...
```

The numbers in the table represent the days (in the month) when a certain event happened. Note: months can have multiple events and events can span over multiple months.

V1, V2 and V3 are three different devices, each having its own separate events. So we have three different time series.

I would like to convert this table to a time series data frame, that is break it down per day for each device. Each row would be one day for one month (for one year) and each column would now only have values of 0 or 1, 0 if no event happened on that day, 1 otherwise (dummy variable). The result would contain three different time series, one for each device. How would I do that?

This is what the output would look like

```
    V0  V1  V2  Day  Month  Year
0    0   0   0    1      1  2015
1    0   0   0    2      1  2015
2    0   0   0    3      1  2015
3    0   0   0    4      1  2015
4    0   0   0    5      1  2015
5    0   1   0    6      1  2015
6    0   1   0    7      1  2015
7    0   1   0    8      1  2015
8    0   1   0    9      1  2015
9    0   1   0   10      1  2015
10   0   0   0   11      1  2015
11   0   0   0   12      1  2015
12   0   0   0   13      1  2015
...
```

Comment: W/hat is the difference between the three columns V1, V1 and V2?

Comment: @Peter V1, V2 and V3 are three different devices, each having its own events. So the result would be three time series, one for each V. Double V1 was a typo.

Comment: Might be helpful to post an example of what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a series of transformations as shown below. Don't know if this is the most efficient way of doing this ...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
tmp=[["","5-9",""],["","",""],["17-","","4- -9 27-"],["-6","",""],["","","-15"]]
df=pd.DataFrame(tmp).rename(columns={0:"V0",1:"V1",2:"V2"})
df["Month"]=np.arange(1,6)
df["Year"]=np.repeat(2015,5)
print(df)
```

```
    V0   V1         V2  Month  Year
0       5-9                 1  2015
1                           2  2015
2  17-       4- -9 27-      3  2015
3   -6                      4  2015
4                  -15      5  2015
```

**1. Stack Only Non-Empty Values**

```
days = df.set_index(['Year', 'Month']).stack().replace('', np.nan).dropna()
print(days)
```

```
Year  Month    
2015  1      V1          5-9
      3      V0          17-
             V2    4- -9 27-
      4      V0           -6
      5      V2          -15
dtype: object
```

**2. Expand Date Ranges**

String such as `"5-9"` need to be converted to an array with length 31, with values between indices 5 - 9 set to 1 and rest to 0. And similarly, for the other rows. This is a string parsing problem left as an exercise :-). In my example below, I am hard coding the solution based on the values in the question.

```
def _fill(arr, start, stop):
  arr[np.arange(start-1, stop)] = 1
  return arr

def expand_days(df_in):
  df_out = df_in.copy()
  days_all = np.zeros(31)

  df_out.loc[2015, 1, 'V1'] = _fill(days_all.copy(), 5, 9)
  df_out.loc[2015, 3, 'V0'] = _fill(days_all.copy(), 17, 31)
  df_out.loc[2015, 3, 'V2'] = _fill(_fill(days_all.copy(), 4, 9), 27, 31)
  df_out.loc[2015, 4, 'V0'] = _fill(days_all.copy(), 1, 6)
  df_out.loc[2015, 5, 'V2'] = _fill(days_all.copy(), 1, 15)

  return df_out

days_ex = expand_days(days)
print(days_ex)
```

```
Year  Month    
2015  1      V1    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ...
      3      V0    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
             V2    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ...
      4      V0    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
      5      V2    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ...
dtype: object
```

**3. Convert an Array to a series of Columns**

```
days_fr = days_ex.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x, index=np.arange(1, 32)))
print(days_fr)
```

```
                1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10 ...    22  \
Year Month                                                      ...         
2015 1     V1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0 ...   0.0   
     3     V0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 ...   1.0   
           V2  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0 ...   0.0   
     4     V0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 ...   0.0   
     5     V2  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0 ...   0.0   

                23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31  
Year Month                                                  
2015 1     V1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
     3     V0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  
           V2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  
     4     V0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
     5     V2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  

[5 rows x 31 columns]
```

**4. Set Correct Index Names And Stack**

```
days_unstacked = days_fr.stack()
days_unstacked.index.set_names(['Year', 'Month', 'Devices', 'Days'], inplace=True)
print(days_unstacked.head())
```

```
Year  Month  Devices  Days
2015  1      V1       1       0.0
                      2       0.0
                      3       0.0
                      4       0.0
                      5       1.0
dtype: float64
```

**5. Unstack And Fill NA's With Zeros**

```
days_stacked = days_unstacked.unstack('Devices').fillna(0).reset_index()
print(days_stacked.head(10))
```

```
Devices  Year  Month  Days   V0   V1   V2
0        2015      1     1  0.0  0.0  0.0
1        2015      1     2  0.0  0.0  0.0
2        2015      1     3  0.0  0.0  0.0
3        2015      1     4  0.0  0.0  0.0
4        2015      1     5  0.0  1.0  0.0
5        2015      1     6  0.0  1.0  0.0
6        2015      1     7  0.0  1.0  0.0
7        2015      1     8  0.0  1.0  0.0
8        2015      1     9  0.0  1.0  0.0
9        2015      1    10  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

The index name of the resulting frame is set to `Devices` which is an artifact of how we setup the problem. It will need to be changed to something else.